# Eliminar elemento de array en PHP

Tags: php, json

He intentado múltiples códigos en PHP para eliminar un elemento de un array de cadenas por su nombre. Ya son dos dias de busquedas infinitas por la web, sin solución alguna.

El string json:

```
["stringNumero1","stringNumero2","stringNumero3","stringNumero4","stringNumero5"]
```

El código PHP:

```
$index = array_search("stringNumero3", $jsonDecodificado);
if($index !== FALSE){
  unset($jsonDecodificado[$index]);
}
echo json_encode($jsonDecodificado);
```

Da como resultado:

```
{0:"stringNumero1",1:"stringNumero2",2:"stringNumero3",3:"stringNumero4",4:"stringNumero5}
```

PS:
La variable `$jsondecodificado` tiene como valor `json_decode(file_get_contents('rutaAlJson'), true)`

Posteriormente intenté eliminando el segundo parámetro `true` de `json_decode()` pero siguió sin dar el resultado esperado, la remoción del string "stringNumero3" dentro del array de strings.

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando utilizas `unset` la llave del arreglo se pierde, lo que hace que las llaves ya no sean consecutivas y `json_encode` lo convierta en un objeto. Lo que puedes hacer es cambiar `unset` por `array_splice`, así:

```
array_splice($jsonDecodificado, $index, 1);
```

Dado que `array_splice` cambia las llaves del arreglo, vuelve a parecer un arreglo de índices numéricos continuos y así `json_encode` lo mantiene cómo arreglo normal

Answer (score 0):

Realiza un `var_dump($jsonDecodificado)` inmediatamente despues de `json_decode(file_get_contents('rutaAlJson')`, probe asi simulando tu file y funciona correctamente:

```
<?php
$txt='["stringNumero1","stringNumero2","stringNumero3","stringNumero4","stringNumero5"]';
$jsonDecodificado = json_decode($txt, true);
echo "ANTES";
var_dump($jsonDecodificado);
echo json_encode($jsonDecodificado);

$index = array_search("stringNumero3", $jsonDecodificado);
if($index !== FALSE){
    //unset($jsonDecodificado[$index]);
    array_splice($jsonDecodificado, $index, true);
}
echo "<br><br>DESPUES";
var_dump($jsonDecodificado);
echo json_encode($jsonDecodificado);
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, pero despues me retorna un json con {} en vez de [] como antes, y cuando uso in_array() me retorna un error de PHP que el array es invalido

Comment: ese es otro tema pense que solo queria que elimine el elemento

Comment: solamente necesito solucionar el error que php arroja cuando el array se ve convertido de [] a {}

Comment: en ese caso reemplaza la linea de unset por "array_splice($jsonDecodificado, $index, true);"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [array_values](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php) asi:

```
echo json_encode(array_values($jsonDecodificado));
```

De esa forma mantienes el uso de `unset` sin problema, ademas puedes mantener el array original sin ninguna alteración del orden de sus indices.